# Dynamic views are not properly loaded

Tags: android

Im retrieving values from sqlite db and trying to  display the values dynamically.

This is how I retrieve the values,

```
List<PendingOrdersDao> contacts = db.getAllPendingOrders();

for (PendingOrdersDao cn : contacts) {
        initView(cn.getProformoInvoiceNumber(), cn.getProformoInvoiceDate());
}
```

When I invoke initView method, it should add views to the layout dynamically depending on the number of entries present in db. Following is my initView method.

```
private void initView(String proformaInvoice, String invoiceDate){

        LinearLayout mLinearLayoutContainer = (LinearLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.dashboard_container);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_fragment, mLinearLayoutContainer, false);

        mProformaInvoice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dashProformaInvoiceNo);
        mInvoiceNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dashInvoiceNo);

        mProformaInvoice.setText(proformaInvoice);
        mInvoiceNumber.setText(invoiceNumber);

        mLinearLayoutContainer.addView(v);
    }
```

The problem is that, there are three entries in the db hence  3views should be displayed but it displays only one view

Comment: Try inflater.inflate(layoutResId, null)

Comment: Is only the last entry in your DB is getting inflated?

Comment: yes it is the last entry

Comment: @Stanly: I tried the same code, and it seems to be working for me. (printing 3 rows)  But i had faced something similar problem earlier. At that time, what i tried was declaring the variables in the method and making them final. Try this! Let me know if it works

Comment: Can you please post your working code

Comment: gottcha! I think you forgot to mention orientation in you LinearLayout. I did that and my whole view was captured by a single view

Comment: i added vertical as my orientation but still the same problem persists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104720/discussion-between-devendra-ranjan-tiwari-and-stanly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my working code :-

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        LinearLayout mLinearLayoutContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test_container);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View v = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mLinearLayoutContainer, false);
        mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        mTextView.setText("This is i : " + i);
        mLinearLayoutContainer.addView(v);

    }
```

See if helps you. :)

Comment: Do you find anything odd??

Comment: still the same problem exists

Comment: even after adding orientation??

Comment: Hey bro... Finally i have found the answer. i have missed setting id so each time the code was adding values to the textview of same id hence only one view was visible.

Comment: Haha.. Good, never thought this could be the problem :)

Comment: me too lol... i  just tried inserting codes randomly and the by the end bingo!! it worked like a charm  :P

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, check the contacts list size.
2. Do you setup correct orientation for your `linear layout`? Vertical or horizontal?

advice

3. Why not to use `RecyclerView` or `ListView`?